# Apple music genre selection screen balls/bubbles

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, uikit, apple-music

I tried to replicate what Apple has done with the genre selection screen for Apple Music. At first I thought it was done with UIViewDynamics but I found out that it was most likely done with SpriteKit due to it having a better physics engine. I tried to import SpriteKit into my singleViewApplication, but it kept failing? I tried a container view to try and store the SpriteKit code because I only wanted it to appear in the middle/top of my screen.

However I found some code that someone has written that replicates what Apple did perfectly, and you can find it [here](https://github.com/ProudOfZiggy/SIFloatingCollection_Swift)

I looked at this code for a very long time and I only got the basic concept on how it functions, but I do not fully understand it?

Could someone look at this code then tell me how they managed to replicate it?

Comment: First of all ty for using my component))
If you want to know something, just open an issue on git, ask all questions you want, and I'll try to provide some answers